# Sales Order Grid issue in Magento 2.4.2: Column not found

Tags: magento, magento2

On admin in Sales Order Grid, I am getting the following error. Please guide on this:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'allocated_sources' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, group_concat(sales_order_item.sku SEPARATOR ", ") AS `skus`, group_concat(sales_order_item.name SEPARATOR ",") AS `names`, `braintree_transaction_details`.`transaction_source` FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_item` ON sales_order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `braintree_transaction_details` ON braintree_transaction_details.order_id = main_table.entity_id GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id` ORDER BY allocated_sources ASC
```

I have one extra column in grid i.e. Allocated Sources.

Comment: I have got same problem 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'allocated_sources' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `braintree_transaction_details`.`transaction_source` FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `braintree_transaction_details` ON braintree_transaction_details.order_id = main_table.entity_id ORDER BY allocated_sources ASC LIMIT 200
Exception in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110

Comment: I have change the role of user and this error auto resolved by changing permissions to users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for the same.
Just override the module sales order grid & add the following code. Upgrade your module & Flush the cache. It will work.

1 - Create a new module with Magento standards
2 - Override file with this content view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="allocated_sources"
                class="Magento\InventoryShippingAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AllocatedSources"
                component="Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi/js/order/grid/cell/allocated-sources">
            <settings>
                <filter>false</filter>
                <label translate="true">Allocated sources</label>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Your problem will be solved.
Thanks,
Rashi

Answer (score 0):

Please check the "allocated_sources" column in your database. I guess it hasn't been created yet or you are joining the wrong table.